# Export variable from function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a class in the coffeescript file:

```
class Grid
  constructor: (size) ->
    @size = size
    @algo = new Algo()
    @cells = @empty()
```

It generate JS file:

```
(function() {
  var Grid;

  Grid = (function() {
    function Grid(size) {
      this.size = size;
      this.algo = new Algo();
      this.cells = this.empty();
    }

    // ...
}).call(this);
```

I have another JS file which I have included to HTML after my first JS file.  In this JS file I want to create an instance of Grid class, but the Grid class is not in the global scope, so I can not do something like this:

```
grid = new Grid(4);
```

How can I use Grid class in the another JS files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `class @Grid` instead.

> [As a shortcut for this.property, you can use @property.](http://coffeescript.org/#operators)

That should change your compiled code to use `this.Grid = (function() {...` where `this` will be `window`.

[Source](http://justinreid.com/coffeescript-global-classes/)